# Handle exception for Blob not present scenario in Azure blob delete client in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have thousands of blobs in the container and have a list of blobs to be deleted fetched from some db.

Now, there is no guarantee that the id/name present in the list is present in the blob. so want to do a deleteIfExist kind of a scenario and

error it throws when blob is not present is NOT :  azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Operation which i can write an exception block for.

It throws something generic like : azure.storage.blob._shared.response_handlers.PartialBatchErrorException: There is a partial failure in the batch operation.

Code below :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str_for_list)
container="name1-entity"
# Instantiate a ContainerClient
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)

file_name = "something.txt"
fileobj = open(file_name, "r")
entityIdsList = [line.rstrip() for line in fileobj]
fileobj.close()

blobs_list = entitysChunk
    print(blobs_list)

    blobs_length = len(blobs_list)
# container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list)
    if blobs_length <= 256:
        container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list)

    else:
        start = 0
        end = 256

        while end <= blobs_length:
        # each time, delete 256 blobs at most
            container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list[start:end])
            start = start + 256
            end = end + 256
            if start < blobs_length and end > blobs_length:
                container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list[start:blobs_length])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,PartialBatchErrorException
conn_str_for_list = "connection-string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str_for_list)
container="blob-container-name"

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)

file_name = "blobs.txt"
fileobj = open(file_name, "r")
entityIdsList = [line.rstrip() for line in fileobj]
fileobj.close()

blobs_list = entityIdsList

print(blobs_list)

try:
    result = container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list)
    for item in result:
        print(item.status_code)
except PartialBatchErrorException as e:
    print(e.message)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.response)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.parts)
    print("-----------------------")
    for part in e.parts:
        if (part.status_code == 202):
            print("Blob delete request was accepted.")
        elif (part.status_code == 404):
            print("Blob does not exist. Consider it deleted.")
        else:
            print("Something else happened. You better take a look at it.")
            print(part)
        print("==============================")
```

Essentially whenever there an exception of type  [`PartialBatchErrorException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.partialbatcherrorexception?view=azure-python), it's `parts` property will have the details about the result of each operation in the batch. You can check the status code of each operation to determine if it was successful (`status code 202`) or failed (`other status code`). If the status code is `404 (Not Found)`, you can assume that the blob does not exist.

Comment: Many thanks for educating about PartialBatchErrorException import and the errors there-in.

Comment: Is there a similar log we can write for success in try method??

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You can iterate over result and print the status code. HTH.